# Mysql give 1030 error, now i can't log in to mysql server to clear cache

Tags: mysql, linux, caching, centos, code-injection

i am working on a linux CentOS server.
Some day ago i discovered that mysql gave error 1030 (no space avaible on the disk).
Yesterday the admin of the server restarted mysql, now it won't restart because mysql can't find space to create a "pid" file.
My question is:
Since i can't access to mysql server, but i can access to the machine, what is the folder where i can find the cache? I think that i have to delete it because some day ago someone attacked us wih a sql injection, in the log i saw that the hacker executed a lot of "select" queries, so i think the problem is the cache

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the mysql process which has filled up the disk. You can scan the disk and find out where the space is being used with (as the root user):

```
du -sh /*
```

This will return a list of directories and their space usage, then you can drill down using:

```
du -sh /var/*
```

Or whatever directory is using the most space.

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to find which partition is full by running `df` command. Ex:

```
/dev/sdb1      105601116 26127676  74086128  27% /
dev              2022860        0   2022860   0% /dev
run              2025640      508   2025132   1% /run
tmpfs            2025640    28704   1996936   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2025640        0   2025640   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            2025640    85100   1940540   5% /tmp
/dev/sda1      307534224 92590832 199298504  32% /data
tmpfs             405128        8    405120   1% /run/user/1000
```

Then for MySQL it's probably your / partition that is full. Try to run `du -sh /var/` (`/var` is the directory mysql stores files). Ex:

```
6.4G    /var/cache
16K /var/db
4.0K    /var/empty
8.0K    /var/games
0   /var/run
585M/var/log
```

It is probably your
`/var/log` directory which is full of log. You can delete some files (e.g., apache logs) to gain space. Better is to detect where the most space is taken in your disk by running `du -sh mydir`, starting from `/` directory and digging to find what to delete.

Comment: Your / is full, as suspected. Now start digging to find where you can save space by running `du -sh /*' then depending on the biggest directory `du -sh /biggest_dir/*` and so on.